# Having trouble using the sum function

Tags: python, python-3.x

The input (list) would be a list similar to `[[1,2],[5,6],[4,6]]`. I am trying to add the whole row together to test if it is even or odd.

```
def evenrow(list):
    for row in list:
        for item in row:
            newNums+=item
            n=sum(newNums)
            print(n)
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all do not use 'list' as variable name. Second you calling sum for int value not for a list and that's why you getting error. Check your code please.

Not sure but your code can looks like:

```
def evenrow(list):
    for row in list:
        value = sum(row)
        if values is even: # put your condition here
            # do something
        else:
            print "Value is odd"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an alternate method:

```
def evenrow(lst):
    return sum(map(sum,lst))%2 == 0 #True if even, False otherwise.
```

This works this way:

The outer `sum` adds up all items of the `map`, which applies `sum` to each item in `lst`.  In python2, map returns a `list` object, while in python3, it returns a `map` object.  This is passed to the outer `sum` function, which adds up all items in your `map`.

```
def evenrow(lst):
    return sum(itertools.chain(*a)) % 2 == 0
```

This expands all the items in `a` (each of the sublists), and chains them together, as a `chain` object.  It then adds together all the items and determines if the sum is even.

Comment: Thank you. I have not used the map method before but the code looks eligant. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the following line of code: `n=sum(newNums)`. You already summed up all the items of row in the `newNums += item` line. Second, you have to declare `newNums` before using it in your code. So, the fixed version of code will look like this:

```
def evenrow(list):
    for row in list:
        newNums = 0
        for item in row:
            newNums += item
        print(newNums)
```

BTW: You should consider accepting answers to some of your previous questions, otherwise nobody will spend their time to answer your new questions.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. One of my two previous questions was closed so I have stopped posting on that. On the other I have responded with thanks for the responses I have gotten. Did I miss something? Sorry I am new.

Comment: If you see the answer that helped you, you can accept it by pressing the tick under the answer's score, so this tick becomes green. It means that you accepted the answer, and community can  answer other questions, without looking into yours. :) Seems like [Artsiom Rudzenka](http://stackoverflow.com/users/781150/artsiom-rudzenka) [gave you a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15238916/885028), so you can accept it.